# Create dropdownlist for 'year' column without showing 0

Tags: php, function

I want to show the year list without 0, I got 2 yearlist which is 2016 and 2017 in table called invoice_template, so I should get yearlist for 2016 and 2017. May I know any idea to solve this issue? Below is the code and image:

```
    public function getYear(){   

        $year = Yii::app()->user->getState('start_year');
        $queryString = "select distinct year from invoice_template where year =:year ORDER BY year ASC";
        $params[':year'] = $year;

        $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($queryString);
        $command->params = $params;            
        $yearList = $command->queryAll();

        return $yearList;

     }
```

[Before the dropdownlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPIt1.png) and [After click the dropdownlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQX4n.png)

Comment: Check if your db tables contains 0 value stored

Comment: I just store 2 value which mean is 2016 and 2017 in 'year' column. I wonder why will show 0 ?

Comment: Please edit your question and show your view code means where u displayed dropdown

Comment: changed. Is that arrary problem? that why show 0?

Comment: is it not the index of the array item : $yearList = array( 0 => '2016') and there is only 1 year because you are comparing year =:year where $year is a single value ($year = Yii::app()->user->getState('start_year');)

Comment: yes! I want it show '2016' only without index.

Comment: if you only want to get a single value then queryAll() is not the corect command - it returns an array

Comment: let say 'year' column now got '2016' and '2017', i want to show them both. what command should i use? need use for loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said in the comments - the queryAll() is the culprit - it returns a nested array: try this - which will return only the results from the queried row

```
$yearList = $command->queryRow();
```

If you want to keep the array - you will need to a a foreach() or other method of traversing the array to display each value.